# What is a good way to define and declare job dependencies on rundeck?

Tags: jobs, exit-code, rundeck

On rundeck workflow scheduling, I want to configure a workflow like this.

> Job Step 1 : returns status "success" 
>  Job Step 2 : checks return
>   status of {Job Step 1} (as "success") and proceeds

Am not sure if adding a flow control attribute like this solves the problem [image: Flow control attribute on rundeck]

**Question 1:** 
At Job Step 1, I can return the job status as follows, but how do I check this status at another job step?

```
(some shell cmd)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    exit_code="success"
else
    exit_code="failure"
fi

echo $exit_code
```

**Question 2:** Is there a way to do this across jobs/workflows in the same/different project?

Answer (score 0):

Flow Control and Job State Conditional allow you to use a custom exit status in one job, and have another job test the exit status of a job.  However, these work across independent Jobs, not within a workflow.

If you want Step 2 to depend on Step 1 of a workflow being successful, right now you would have to set the workflow to "keepgoing on failure=false", which will exit the workflow as soon as Step 1 fails.